# Function of the という preceding のだろうか?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> 夕弦は七罪ではなかった。ならば残るは十香、亜衣、殿町、美衣の中の誰かだということなのだろうか。だとしても、夕弦以外に明確に士道の指名を逃れられたと思われる人物はいない。まさか、本当にただ勝負を楽しむためだけに、七罪は自分を危険に晒していた**というのだろうか**……？
>
> しかしもしそう考えるのなら、その前提自体が無意味ということになってしまう。七罪が勝負を楽しんでいるというのなら、単純に今残っている三人の中に彼女がいるということもーー
>
> 頭の中で思考が堂々巡りになる。

Context: 七罪 was playing a game with 士道, the protagonist. 七罪 had the ability to transform into other people and now she had transformed into one of the 12 friends of 士道’s. And 七罪 asked 士道 to guess who she was pretending to be. Each time 士道 guessed wrongly, 七罪 would make two of the friends disappear.

Question: Can we omit the という of the bold part? If not, why? (For example, does the という just mean “say” in this context?)

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Yes, という just means "to say" in this case. You could omit という here, but the sentence would  take on a different meaning. The original here means:

> 七罪は自分を危険に晒していたというのだろうか？
>
>  So what you're saying 七罪 exposed herself to danger?

Without it, there would be no implication that someone else is "saying" this information. It sounds more like the person him/herself is making this assumption.

> 七罪は自分を危険に晒していたのだろうか？
>
>  (I wonder if) 七罪 exposed herself to danger?